# Duplicate Rows JCR-SQl2 AEM

Tags: java, aem, jcr-sql2

I've faced with a duplicate rows issue when I use **JCR-SQl2** query for getting data in **AEM 6.3.1**. I attached the SQl2 query below.

```
SELECT s.* FROM [rep:User] AS s
LEFT OUTER JOIN [nt:base] AS c ON
ischildnode(c, s)
WHERE (ISDESCENDANTNODE(s,"/home/users"))
and s.[rep:authorizableId] = {0} or c.[email] = {0}
```

Is there a way to use `"Select DISTINCT"` statement in **JCR-SQL2** query or something like that for removing the duplicate rows of result.

Comment: Not sure if that is possible. One way to solve this is to add the results to a Set to remove duplicates. I tried your query on our instance and always only get one result? Not 100% sure what you try to achieve and how you get duplicates. Maybe you can expand a bit on what you are trying to do and give us some sample data?

Comment: Thank you for your support,  Jens.  About the issue, when we use the query tool of AEM, it always returns only one row, but when I use the jcr API (javax.jcr.query.Query) then I always receive the result of the duplicate rows.
Currently, my issue's fixing by a solution like your suggestion, but I was not comfortable with this.